# Convert a String to an ObservableValue<String>

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I would like to create a `TableView`. In my `.fxml` controller, I have these two columns:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Log, String> planeRegistrationColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Log, String> planeTypeColumn;
```

The log class has an attribute `Plane` which is a Plane instance. But the `setCellValueFactory` doesn't seem to like it:

```
planeRegistrationColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().planeProperty().get().getRegistration());
```

`getRegistration()` returns a String, but it needs an `ObservableValue<String>`. Is it a conception problem? And if not, how to can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the string you get in some kind of observable value:

```
planeRegistrationColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().planeProperty().get().getRegistration()));
```